# How to initilize a list using Vars

Tags: c#, list

I have a class called Players that holds various player attributes.  I want to use a loop to initialize a list of Players based on certain user input.  I will then use the list to play a card game with each of the players.  I guess the List needs to be global in scope.

I can't figure out how to initialize the list since I can't seem to user a var 
in the name field when trying to create a new Player.

Thanks

```
    class Players
{
    public string name;
    public double bank;
    public Hands  playerHands; //A List of hands played

    public Players ()
    {
        name = "Unknown";
        bank = 0.0;
        playerHands  = null;
    }

    public Players(string name, double bank, Hands playerHands)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.bank = bank;
        this.playerHands = playerHands;
    }
}

class Program
{
    private static int numOfPlayers;
    private static int numOfDecks;
    private static List<Cards> shoe;

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8; //required to display special characters
        Hands playerHands = new Hands();
        Hands dealerHands = new Hands();
        SetUpTable();

        //Initilize Players
        Players player = new Players("Ken", 100.00, playerHands);
        Players dealer = new Players("Dealer", 0.0, dealerHands);
        int dealerScore = 0, playerScore = 0;

        //Deal initial cards
        //The deal starts with the dealer who gets the first card face down

            Cards dealerUpCard = null;
            Hand dealerHand = new Hand();
            Hand playerHand = new Hand();
            dealer.playerHands.addHand(dealerHand);
            player.playerHands.addHand(playerHand);

            for (int iii = 1; iii < 3; iii++)
            {   
                //Deal dealer's hand                          
                dealerHand.addCard(shoe[0]);
                dealerScore += shoe[0].value;
                if (iii == 2) { dealerUpCard = shoe[0]; }
                shoe.RemoveAt(0);

                //Deal Player's aHand           
                playerHand.addCard(shoe[0]);             
                playerScore += shoe[0].value;
                shoe.RemoveAt(0);
            }

        //Print out the test hands
        displayHand(dealer);            
        displayHand(player);
        Console.Read();
    }

    static void displayHand(Players player)
    {
        //Print out the test hands
        for (int i = 0; i < player.playerHands.hands.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}'s hand: ", player.name);
            for (int j = 0; j < player.playerHands.hands[i].hand.Count; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(" {0}{1} ", player.playerHands.hands[i].hand[j].rank, (char)player.playerHands.hands[i].hand[j].suit);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    static void SetUpTable()
    {
        //Create players
        numOfPlayers = validateUserInput("How many players (1-6)?",1,6);
        for (int i = 0; i<numOfPlayers; i++)
            {   //get player elements
                //initiliz a new unique player in the Players list
                //ie: Players player = new Players("Ken", 100.00, playerHands);
            }

        //Create shoe of cards
        numOfDecks = validateUserInput("How many decks of cards (1-8)?", 1, 8);          
        shoe = Deck.createDeck(numOfDecks);
        Deck.shuffleDeck(shoe, numOfDecks);          
    }
}
```

Comment: Paste the entire class that holds `SetUpTable`. Where is the Players object that hold the list ?

Comment: Why don't you declare a `var lstPlayers = new List<Players>();`, then `Add` items in to it in the loop? `lstPlayers.Add(new Players(...));`.

Comment: You mention a list of players, but see that nowhere in your code, all I see is a single player held in a field.

Comment: Thanks -- correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public List<Players> ListOfPlayers=new List<Players>();
static void SetUpTable()
{
    //Create players
    numOfPlayers = 6;

    for (int i = 0; i<numOfPlayers; i++)
        {   
          ListOfPlayers.Add(new Players());
          //or with initial values with ctor:
          ListOfPlayers.Add(new Players("Ken", 100.00, playerHands));
          //or
          ListOfPlayers.Add(new Players(){name="Ken", bank=100.00, playerHands=_playerHands});
            //ie: Players player = new Players("Ken", 100.00, playerHands);
        }

}
```

Comment: Thanks seems always to be a simple answer.